# How do I get the memberships (distribution groups) of an Outlook contact programmatically?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, com-interop, win32com

Using office Outlook, we can find the '**Memberships**' tab when we click and expand a contact, this 'Memberships' tab shows the list of emails that the user is subscribed to.

For example, Employee X (x.x@zcompany.com / id123@zcompany.com) under the Data Department of Z Company is subscribed to the following distribution groups:

- datateam@zcompany.com
- allemployeees@zcompany.com
- dataweekly@zcompany.com
- it.uk@zcompany.com
- znewsletter@zcompany.com

I would like to **get the list of emails the user is subscribed to** by inputting either the **user's email** or **user's organization ID**.

I found a few potential solutions but do not know exactly how to implement them:

1. Outlook Interop [GetMemberOfList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-information-about-all-distribution-lists-of-which-the-current-user-is-a-member) and [GetExchangeDistributionList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry.getexchangedistributionlist?view=outlook-pia)
2. [Using Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
3. [VBA automation for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/address-book/list-the-groups-that-my-manager-belongs-to)
4. [Reverse engineering using ExchangePowershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-group?view=exchange-ps)
5. [Using RPA to imitate user actions on Outlook](https://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/outlook-email-automation)

Wonder if someone with experience doing this can provide some advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OOM, call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient`, `Recipient.Resolve`, `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()`.  `ExchangeUser` exposes `GetMemberOfList()` method, which returns `IAddressEntries` object.

Comment: Hi yes, I figured this out yesterday as well however not using Application.Session, it didn't work for me, namespace MAPI worked for me. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: `Application.Session` will be null if Outlook is was not running prior to you creating an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object. In that case, `Namespace` object comes from `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` and you need to call `Namespace.Logon`.